# Как сделать бой в онлайн-игре?

Tags: php

Как сделать бой в онлайн-игре и потом его бросить любому игроку в онлайн? Для этого все есть типа хп, атака и т.п.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень просто. В чат кидается ссылка, например:

```
<a href='/?unitId=27845&enemyId=111999'>Вызываю на бой!!!</a>
```

//php:

```
if(!empty($_GET['unitId'])){
if($_GET['unitId']!=$_GET['enemyId']){
fight($_GET['enemyId'],$_GET['unitId']);// Функция боя. Применяет attack и hurt методы, пока у кого-то hp не станут отрицательными.
}
}
```

Comment: о спасибо =)